How does flutter set initialization options for CupertinoPicker
I want to choose the second option by default, how should I set it
How many ways
showCupertinoModalPopup(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (c) {
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 300,
                              child: Material(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  child: CupertinoPicker(
                                    itemExtent: 60,
                                    onSelectedItemChanged: (c) {},
                                    children: List.generate(
                                      30,
                                      (v) {
                                        return ListTile(
                                          title: const Text('data'),
                                          subtitle: Text('$c'),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );

please help me
I want to choose the second option by default, how should I set it

Add this to you CupertinoPicker
scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: ...)
